# Angular4 passing a subscription data method is failing in a child

Tags: angular

I have a **data** service, which looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http/src/response';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import { ICategory } from "../shared/interfaces/category.shared";

const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;
const API_Path = '/categories';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryDataService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  public list(includes?: string): Observable<ICategory[]> {
    return this._http
      .get<ICategory[]>(API_URL + API_Path, { params: { includes: includes || '' } })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }
}
```

Injecting this into a component and invoking it works as expected. But, if I pass the method into the component as an **@Input** function, it fails.
This is how I am declaring it in my **app.component**:

```
constructor(
  public categoryData: CategoryDataService
) {
}
```

Then I pass it to my child component like this:

```
<pq-button [list]="categoryData.list" (onSelect)="setCategory($event)" title="Category"></pq-button>
```

the **component** looks like this:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'pq-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss']
})
export class ButtonComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() list: Function;
  @Input() title: string;
  @Output() onSelect = new EventEmitter<string>(); 
  selected:string;
  items: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.list().subscribe(response => this.items = response);
  }

  set($event) {
    this.onSelect.emit($event);
  } 
}
```

As you can see, I look for an input method and then using `ngAfterViewInit`, I try to call the method and **subscribe** to its results. I did try `ngOnInit`, but was getting the same error I get now, which is:

> annot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at ButtonComponent.CategoryDataService.list

It looks like the `HttpClient` is undefined, but I have no idea why.
If I looks in my **app.module** I can see that I have it imported like this:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and it is part of the **imports** array:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CategoryComponent,
    CriteriaComponent,
    PersonaComponent,
    SelectorComponent,
    ButtonComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: you propably have the wrong "this" context.
Try transform your list function into an arrow function:

    `public list = (includes?: string): Observable<ICriteria[]> => {
        return this._http
          .get<ICriteria[]>(API_URL + API_Path, { params: { includes: includes || '' } })
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }`

Comment: I can see `CategoryDataService`, and `CriteriaDataService`, which one is correct?

Comment: You are loosing `this` context.

Comment: @A.Winnen, you were correct, if you put this as an answer, I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you propably have the wrong "this" context.
Try to transform your list() function into an arrow function to keep the context of CategoryDataService:

```js
public list = (includes?: string): Observable<ICriteria[]> => {
    return this._http
      .get<ICriteria[]>(API_URL + API_Path, { params: { includes: includes || '' } })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```